# Как удалить стартовую страницу в VS при создании проекта на ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Какие контроллеры удалить или что-то в этом роде. Я хотел создать простую программу, но выдает стартовую страницу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выбрать шаблон empty и отметить галку "MVC" - будет пусто и чисто

Comment: Заглавная странице - это HomeController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбрать шаблон empty и отметить галку "MVC" - будет пусто и чисто.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]